# cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'

Tags: java, android

Не могу понять в чем ошибка

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bodyNotification);
```

Comment: Отсутствует метод `findViewById`.

Comment: Где вы вызываете этот метод?

Comment: Кирилл Малышев, не в MainActivity

Comment: @КириллМалышев, ^^^

Comment: Как использовать findViewById не в MainActivity?

Comment: @Malyuga, покажите где именно вы используете этот код.

Comment: @Malyuga вы вызываете этот метод во фрагменте?

Comment: View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.лэйаут_фрагмента, container, false);
TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bodyNotification);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `findViewById()` определен в классе `Activity` и `View`

[документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int))

Конструкция:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bodyNotification);
```

неявно ссылается на `this`, который должен являться экземпляром `Activity` или `View`, соответственно, его отсутствие автоматически означает, что надо где-то взять `Activity` или `View`